# Implement dotnet core Identity Provider server for Google

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, single-sign-on, saml

I want to authenticate my GSuite users using my own .net core web application as Identity Provider.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en

However, I don't know where to even start. I've been actively and diligently looking for the solution but all of them are from commerce company and it is a bit over-kill to use their service.

A good commercial provider is:
https://www.componentpro.com/products/saml

Is there a hidden gem open source libraries somewhere that I missed?

I know this question is quite general but any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: You could use Microsoft WIF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx directly.

However I would find it quite challenging to really implement a SAMLv2 compliant Identity Provider yourself.

Could it be that you actually only want to provide SSO to your web application leveraging Google's SAMLv2 IdP?

Comment: You can use Identity Server 4 http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html?highlight=google#adding-google-support

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr `WIF` is not meant to act as an IdP, just as an SP. It also has no support for SAML2-P (protocol) wich is needed. Your link also takes to old `WIF` which has been deprecated for some years now. `WIF` is a no-go here. There is no official SAML2 stack for .NET and you must have good faith to trust on the only two 'production-ready' paid components.

Comment: @AndersonMatos thanks for pointing this out. As Azure AD and ADFS offers SAMLv2 support, I'm sure Microsoft is using some library. I thought at least in ADFS WIF is used for this.

Comment: yes, there must be some libraries out there already :)

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There is NO official `SAML2` stack for .NET.

To build a SAML-compliant `Identity Provider` for federated identity you'll need not only SAML tokens but SAML protocol (v2 is the only one I've seen being supported by external providers like Google, Okta, Auth0, AWS Cognito and others). They all use either SAML 1.1 or 2.0 *tokens* from within SAML 2.0 *protocol*.

From a long research (still goind on) I came to only one free SAML2 library I'd trust: `Sustainsys` (you can find it on NuGet). It will enable SAML2 (including the protocol) on your application, perform assertion validation and all. Looks interesting but it will work only for new projects.

You can rely on two paid suites, too: `ComponentPro` and `ComponentSpace` (the last one *sounds* more stable/robust but it's merely a feeling, as you cannot find real-proof that it has been used by all those companies on a real-world production app.

You can create a SAML2-P compliant app/module but you'll have to handle signatures, message receival, validation, assertions and more. I'd recommend *against* that as it's quite easy to miss something which could later be exploited as a security breach.

### You might use other federation alternatives

SAML is not the only path here. You might give a try to `OpenID Connect` or `WS-Federation` as well. Check more on `Authentication Federation` topic and you'll find other protocols. One might solve your problem easier than with `SAML`.

Comment: It would really be interesting what the actual use-case is as the question mentioned 'Identity Provider' which could also indicate 'authentication' and not 'SSO' (through what ever protocol). Potentially the questions was not phrased correctly.

Comment: I mention Identity Provider as that is the term that Google are using; it's not crystal clear but don't know how to make it clearer :)

Comment: @Anderson-matos FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Anderson here.

Some points:

Do **NOT** write your own - it's hard and insecure.

A [list](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) of the stacks you can use.

A [list](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/saml-stacks-the-next-step-the-connecting-series-552595e1fd3) of how to use them.

Yes - identityserver is a good choice.

I have used ComponentSpace, Rock Solid Knowledge and Sustainsys. They are all good products and I can recommend them.

Another option is to use Identity as a Service e.g. Azure AD. Auth0, Okta etc. They all support SAML.